# Erro de acentuação

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com um problema no Laravel de codificação.

Já tentei mudar no php.ini(charset=ISO-8859-1).

Já fui no  arquivo header.php do script que estou usando tentar mudar o charset e também não consegui.

Comment: Já tentou alterar para UTF-8? Tentou também utilizar a tag <meta charset="UTF-8"> dentro da tag <head></head> de seu arquivo?

Comment: não funcionou!.

Comment: Fiz uma pesquisa rápida e encontrei essas duas situações: [http://laravel.io/forum/07-30-2014-problem-with-utf8-or-unicode] e [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364979/laravel-4-seeding-accents] espero que ajude com seu problema...

Comment: Parceiro, as informações que estão dando problema estão vindo de algum banco de dados ou está direto no código???